# Lower resistance resistor in place of a higher resistance one

Tags: resistors, 555

I drew this small circuit from a design a friend gave me to blink an LED, but I am missing a certain component. I am missing a 12KΩ resistor. Can I get away with a 10KΩ resistor in its place?
[image]

Comment: What do the equations for designing 555 circuits tell you? You should be able to find this on the wikipedia entry for the 555.

Comment: You "designed" this circuit and you cannot figure out what the difference from 12K to 10K would cause??  From your question it would seem that it is more likely that you COPIED this circuit from some place.

Comment: that 20% difference is sometimes within specs for, say, the capacitor.. so if precision was really an issue you'd have to worry about other things too..

Comment: @MichaelKaras Here I edited it to make you happy. Happy?

Comment: It's ok, everyone, when I assembled the circuit, it didn't work! why? may you ask? because... I HAVE NO CLUE, I DUNNO IF IT IS A BATTERY ISSUE OR WHAT, BUT MY STUPID LED WON"T CLICK

Comment: sorry about the typo in the last comment, I was very angry.

Comment: Now I really wish I could delete this question. It's super embarrassing to have on my profile, especially because of how stupid it is, and because the answer should have been obvious. I'm quite a bit wiser now, but every time I see this it's like a hard blow to the face.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it will work, just with slightly different timing characteristics.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Astable for how to calculate the frequency, on time, and off time.

Answer (score 2):

What values do you have? If you can add a resistor put your 10k + a 2k to achive your original design. (or 10k + 1k + 1k, etc)

Comment: I was aiming for small on this circut, i was planning on putting it in a tyny cylinder about an inch in diameter, it was really a test to see if I could do a soldering joint strong enough to hold up to... let's say 20gs at a small point in time (about 1 nanosecond) and average about 15g over 8.6 seconds (I put it in a model rocket)   (yes it survived)